# Secondary monitor for under £150

Tags: monitors

I currently have a 24" BenQ XL2430T 144hz monitor. I am looking for a secondary 1080p monitor that will be used primarily for watching videos and other non-gaming related tasks. I will be doing all my gaming on my main monitor so a fast response rate is not neccessary.

I would however, like something bright and colourful with an IPS panel with preferably a black bezel and stand. 16:9 ratio is a must for me and the mointor must have a DVI or HDMI connection (preferably both!). I always use my headphones so built-in speakers is not needed.

So far I have been looking at [LG 24MB35PH](http://www.amazon.co.uk/LG-24MP57VQ-Monitor-1920x1080-HDMI/dp/B00UNBALBY/ref=pd_cp_147_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=1JEE8QWBBKTEE9KGY6NK) and the [Acer G246-LBBID](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Acer-G246HLBBID-24-inch-Monitor-EcoDisplay/dp/B008I39WXC/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1448442078&sr=8-6&keywords=24%22%20computer%20monitor%20ips). If the recommendation was good enough I would not mind going slightly over the £150 budget. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what the policy is on links, but [this](http://www.ebuyer.com/602734-aoc-e2470swda-23-6-led-vga-dvi-monitor-e2470swda) is what I'm running right now.. Its pretty, backlit and only £99 excluding delivery

Comment: It does look like a nice monitor however I do think I would like an IPS panel on the one I would get

Comment: Sorry, I missed the note on the IPS panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend bought an [Asus VX239W](http://www.amazon.co.uk/VX239H-W-Widescreen-Multimedia-Monitor-1920x1080/dp/B00GGQFOVW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448551402&sr=8-1&keywords=ASUS%20VX239W) for a similar use case, and after seeing it a couple of times, I'm considering it too. Great image quality and overall screen for the price.

But buy it in [Spain](http://www.amazon.es/ASUS-VX239W-Monitor-1920-blanco/dp/B00GGQFOVW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448551547&sr=8-1&keywords=ASUS%20VX239W) for example, much better price considering the exchange rate.

Comment: I think that does look like the winner, a lot of good reviews and has won awards on overclockers and other sites. Although the one you have linked seems to be the white one, had to look on other sites for the black version!